# DDD: Reference another aggregates child entity

Tags: reference, transactions, domain-driven-design, entity, aggregate

I currently digging into **DDD** and need a little enlightment.

I have two entities

- `Temple`
- `TempleVariant`

`Temple` (earpiece) contains the **base information** (name, description,...) and has n **variants** which have **technical descriptions** (CAD-drawing, size,...)

My first impression was:
`Temple` and `TempleVariant` form an aggregate - they **belong together**:
They seem very tightly coupled

- if I delete a `Temple` all `TempleVariant`s should be **deleted likewise**
- `TempleVariant`s **cannot exist without** `Temple` (at least it makes no sense)

But then I read that **nothing outside** the aggregate root is **allowed to reference an entity inside** another aggregate. But actually **not `Temple` is referenced** by outside entities but the **`TempleVariants`**.

Does this mean that in (DDD) reality `Temple` and `TempleVariant` are ***different* aggregates** which *just seem* to be an aggregate?

But then, what if I delete `Temple`? As I said `TempleVariant`s must also be deleted. But that would then violate the rule "One aggregate-change - one transaction" (or what it is called :)) because my "feeling" is that I would have to delete them in one transaction...

### So my questions are:

- are those ***two*** aggregates?
- if so: how to handle deletes?

Lg
warappa

Comment: Does it make sense for a `TempleVariant` to have it's own unique identity? I would instead make its identity relative to its parent, eg. `Temple 12345, variant 2`.

Comment: We need more information about Temple and TempleVariants, more exactly how they behave in the 'real world'.

Comment: @MattDavey: that would be a possible way, although I've no experience with this "technique" by now...

Answer (score 4):

Each class in the domain model should map the ubiquitous language that you learn from a domain expert. This look a quite interesting domain, btw.

To me, there are two distict path to cope with your concerns.

You should remember that aggregates are required to ensure business invariants. 
That is: they recieve [commands](http://epic.tesio.it/doc/manual/command_query_separation.html) that change their state and they are responsible to avoid invalid operation (through proper [exceptions](http://epic.tesio.it/2012/12/05/exceptions-are-the-norm.html)).
More often than not they are entities since they hold an identity.

**`TempleVariant`s as Value Objects**

If (and only if) the instances of TempleVariant are required to handle business rules, they should be part of the aggregate. That is, the `Temple` contains them.
However they should be immutable objects: only the `Temple` can recieve commands that change its state (always as a whole).

In this case when you delete a Temple, all the connected TempleVariants disappear. Still, in most of DDD applications that I have developed, no entity gets deleted: they are just archived. But I'm used to financial applications and domains, may be that in your domain deleting temples is the right thing to do.

**`TempleVariant`s as DTOs**

If no command in the `Temple` requires any `TempleVariant` to ensure business rules, the letter are probably just useful descriptive data that can be handled with proper DTOs mapping the DB schema. In this case, I would define an infrastructural services that returns all the variants for a specified `Temple`.

In this case you could expose the [shared identifier](http://epic.tesio.it/doc/manual/shared_identifiers.html) of the related `Temple` in the DTOs but it's not required.

For further informations on aggregate design I strongly suggest you to read the [Vernon's essays on aggregate design](https://vaughnvernon.co/?p=139).

Answer (score 0):

The violated rules and MikeSW's question about behaviour in 'real world' made me rethink my approach. After a talk with the domain expert I realised that my approach *didn't match the domain*, therefore violating ddd. I'm currently redesigning my models.

@Question:
If I left the `TempleVariant`s in the `Temple` model, I would have gone with the "**identity-relative-to-its-parent**" approach to have a posibility to reference a variant (as MattDavey suggested). **But the more important error in design would still be present.**

If the basic design *would have been right*, I would have made both **separate aggregate roots**. It would have worked (from my perspective) but **again** it would have **covered a desing error** (at least in my case).

**Generally**, I think, **if ddd rules are violated**, it's good to **take a step back**, **review** the actual business and check wheater what you've got really matches you domain - or not.

Thank you for your help!